After a patch number upgrade, VirtualBox 7.0.18 shows an error "Can't enumerate USB devices"
On a Windows 10 physical host, we made an upgrade to the VirtualBox on the patch number's level, from an earlier version within v7.0.x to v7.0.18. So, the major and minor versions stayed the same.
After the upgrade, we got the following error. Please see more details below, and let me know if you need more information.
It's the first time we encounter this error, so we highly appreciate any hints and suggestions.
More Details:
The error message:
Can't enumerate USB devices ...

Failed to enumerate host USB devices

Could not load the Host USB Proxy Service (VERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND). 
The service might not be installed on the host computer.

Result Code: E_FAIL (0X00004005)
Component: HostWrap
Interface IHost {...}

Partial screenshot of the error message displayed on the VirtualBox Manager GUI:


For me this issue also appeared under similar conditions. I checked the website and manually downloaded 7.1.4, which seems to have solved the issue...
